# Why does Curl redirect?

Tags: laravel, redirect, curl

I am using Laravel. And I am doing a GET request in Curl to get value from my own API.. But in response, it redirects to login page. why does it redirect and simple not execute the script given in the url?

Comment: Probably because the route is protected by `auth` middleware.

Comment: How do I prevent that? I only want my script to be executed and not redirected?

Comment: Simply disable the `auth` middleware if you want to test or implement a different auth mechanism like `JWT`, [could be helpful](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs).

Comment: Thankyou soooo much... you are a life saver... I never knew laravel has this feature of auth middleware... since i am very much new to laravel... it took me soo many days to find the solution. Nothing worked. But it works now. Thankyou soo much..

Comment: Most Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

For people who are facing the same issue..
Laravel has this Auth Middleware which does authentication for all the request routes inside a controller. You need to just add an api exception. Auth wont authenticate your route and will execute your code as it is.

```
 class AdminController extends Controller {
 public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['sendEmailAsync']]);
}
```

What Curl was doing was sending an ajax request without user authentication. Because of that, whenever the request was made, it redirected to login page for user to authenticate instead of executing the script.